# Locus of points where the fibres continue to remain injective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have been trying to work on a problem which requires the construction of certain flat families. I have the following doubt. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a flat family of projective varieties. Let $F$ be a torsion free coherent sheaf on $X$ and $E$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$. Suppose that there is a an injective morphism $0\rightarrow F\rightarrow E$.

Consider the locus $\{y\in Y : F_y\subset E_y\}$. Is this set an open set? This is non-empty and contains the dense open set $U\subset Y$ which is the maximal open set over which the cokernel is flat. Are these open sets the same?

In my situation $F$ is a rank 1 torsion-free sheaf and $E=O_X$. So an answer even for this situation would be helpful.

Comment: In Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory", this is Theorem 22.5, p. 176.

Comment: @JasonStarr, thanks for the reference! I just looked at the theorem. I understand that if $E/F$ is flat over some subscheme of $Y$ then the injectivity holds for those points of the subscheme. Does it mean that the injectivity locus is precisely the maximal open set where $E/F$ is flatn. In other words is the injectivity locus an open set?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.